# How to make Flask log chained exceptions in unhandled exceptions?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, flask, error-logging

Python 3 introduced exception chaining, so this:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def blow_up():
    try:
        impossible = 42 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError as zde:
        raise MyException('Uh oh!') from zde

try:
    blow_up()
except:
    logger.exception('It blew up!')
```

Produces this:

```
It blew up!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ka-boom.py", line 10, in blow_up
    impossible = 42 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ka-boom.py", line 15, in <module>
    blow_up()
  File "ka-boom.py", line 12, in blow_up
    raise MyException('Uh oh!') from zde
MyException: Uh oh!
```

But when an unhandled exception gets thrown in a Flask view method, the `__cause__` doesn't get logged, which makes debugging hard.

I can do this:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def better_exception_handler(error):
    current_app.logger.exception('Whoopsie!')
    return 'Internal server error', 500
```

but I feel uncomfortable capturing all exceptions like this, and it doesn't feel very elegant. Is there a way to get Flask's built-in exception handler to log the chained exception?

Comment: In 0.12 the Flask logger is set to not propagate the log events up in the logging module hierarchly so if you 'listen' to the root logger probably don't get nothing. Only happens with chained exceptions or with all logged events?

Comment: @tinproject: I do see exceptions in the logs (or at least the console), and everything I send to `current_app.logger`, just not the chained exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Can you supply the version of Python and Flask that you're using? With Python 3.5.2 and Flask 0.12.1 I'm seeing what you're saying should happen.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/error')
def error_out():
    try:
        blow_up()
    except:
        app.logger.exception('it blew up!')
        return 'something went wrong'
    return 'everything is a-ok!'


def blow_up():
    try:
        impossible = 42 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError as zde:
        raise MyExc('Uh oh!') from zde


class MyExc(Exception):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Hitting `localhost:5000/error` for me will then log the following in the console:

```
Seaking:flask-err rdbaker $ ~/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/python app.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2017-05-15 12:19:52,229] ERROR in app: it blew up!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 21, in blow_up
    impossible = 42 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 12, in error_out
    blow_up()
  File "app.py", line 23, in blow_up
    raise MyExc('Uh oh!') from zde
MyExc: Uh oh!
127.0.0.1 - - [15/May/2017 12:19:52] "GET /error HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and I see the text `something went wrong` in my browser.

Comment: Python 3.6.1 and Flask 0.12, but when I manually log to `current_app.logger`, the chained exceptions do indeed appear. The exceptions I was seeing were unhandled ones in the view method. I've updated my question to make this clear.